Why does (type)-1 return the max value for a type in C++?
While reading the source code for RakNet on GitHub, I came across the following in RakNetDefines.h.
typedef unsigned char RPCIndex;
const int MAX_RPC_MAP_SIZE=((RPCIndex)-1)-1;
const int UNDEFINED_RPC_INDEX=((RPCIndex)-1);

When running the following code via an online C++ compiler:
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned char RPCIndex;
const int MAX_RPC_MAP_SIZE=((RPCIndex)-1)-1;
const int UNDEFINED_RPC_INDEX=((RPCIndex)-1);

int main() {
    std::cout << MAX_RPC_MAP_SIZE    << " ";
    std::cout << UNDEFINED_RPC_INDEX;
    return 0;
}

I get 254 255 as the output. While I know that 255 is (typically) the maximum value for an unsigned char in C++, I was shocked to see that simply putting the name of a type and subtracting one from it resulted in it's maximum value. Furthermore, writing (RPCIndex)-0 evaluates to 0. Why is this the case in C++? Is there a historical reason for it, is it just convenient, or am I missing something?

Related: Is it safe to assign -1 to an unsigned int to get the max value?

(type)-1 only gives the maximum value of type if type is an unsigned integral type.

That's the definition of two's complement. Unsigned integral types are guaranteed to implement two's complement. Furthur more, the negative sign is not part the literal; it's the application of negation operator on the literal. You must take caution however; narrowing issues and litersl type mismatches can cause trouble in general case.

(RPCIndex)-1 is parsed as a C-style cast expression of the form (T)E where T is a type and E an unary expression.
In this case T is the type RPCIndex and E is the expression -1 which is a unary minus operator applied to the 1 integer literal.
The result is the value -1 converted to RPCIndex. Because RPCIndex is an unsigned integral type, the result is the representable value of RPCIndex congruent to -1 modulo 2**w where w is the width of the RPCIndex integer type. In other words, it produces 2**w-1, the largest representable value of the unsigned integer type.
I guess you can see how (RPCIndex)-0  works...

This -1 cast trick originates from C where there is no other way to name the maximum value of some aliased unsigned integer type without knowing what it aliases or what its maximum value is apriori.
In C++ it can be expressed much more clearly what the intent is with std::numeric_limits from <limits>. The -1 trick is not necessary anymore:
const int UNDEFINED_RPC_INDEX = std::numeric_limits<RPCIndex>::max();

In general the code looks more like C than (modern) C++ code, although it behaves as expected in C++ as well.

Ah, I see! Since -1 is being cast to an unsigned type, it becomes the max unsigned value (Since -1 in two's compliment is represented as, say, 0xFFFF for a 16-bit integer). Am I understanding you correctly?

@Whirvis Two's complement or anything else about the representation doesn't matter. The behavior of a conversion from (un)signed to unsigned integer (but not to signed integer) has always been defined exactly in terms of values: It produces the smallest representable value congruent to the source value modulo 2**w, i.e. -1 as source value always produces the largest representable value of the unsigned target type 2**w - 1. That's true even in one's-complement representation. (Since C++20 however, C++ supports only two's-complement anyway.)

include <limits.h> anc C macro equivalent of numeric_limits are available. I don't recommend macros and C alternatives in presence of elegant C++ utilities; my point is that you never need such hacks.

@Red.Wave That doesn't work if you have a type alias unless you always declare corresponding *_MAX macros for each type alias as well. You can't know which of the <limits.h> macros you should use without looking through the alias otherwise, which defeats the purpose of the alias.

@user17732522 agreed. But it's there and better than nothing. I don't recommend macros; but more importantly, I DRY () in any context.

What is happening is you are doing a C style cast.  (RPCIndex)-1 says cast -1, which is an int to a RPCIndex.  RPCIndex is an alias for unsigned char, and the key thing there is that it is unsigned.
With unsigned types, they do not go negative.  Instead they wrap modulo 2n where n is the bit width of the type.  This means that -1 becomes 2n - 1 which is the max value for the type.
